# Exhaust fan in lighting circuit

Tags: electrical

There is an exhaust fan in the lighting circuit, Is it acceptable as per NEC to accommodate Exhaust fan and lighting load in same circuit

Comment: I agree with both answers below +, with that said the area I currently live requires bathroom vent fans to remain on for 10 minutes after the light goes off /or 10 minutes after an occupancy sensor no longer detects movement. It’s a local thing so I only leave as a comment.

Comment: @EdBeal That goes to switch/control issues. But it could still be on the same *circuit* as the lights.

Comment: What planet would that be? Is that for all types of construction?

Comment: @EdBeal I'm just curious, where do you live? It seems odd that something like that would actually be in the building code.

Comment: I read the question as can they be combined on 1 switch , of course they could be on the same branch circuit. I said nothing about separate circuits but that the fan had to stay on the occupancy sensor type control is just 1 switch. Oregon requires residential bathrooms to have the delay off fan, I think it is an energy code thing that they adopted or someone told me that.

Comment: @EdBeal *in same circuit* sounds pretty clear to me.

Comment: Ok some nice some can’t pull their head out it depends on the AHJ, if a fan and light can be controlled by the same switch. It is always ok to have them on the same branch circuit.

Answer (score 2):

Since there are plenty of combination kitchen exhaust fan + light and bath exhaust fan + light (and even bath exhaust fan + light + heat) devices, this is clearly OK.

In general, residential exhaust fans require very little power and combining with lights should not be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is acceptable. Many bathroom fans include lights with the intention of both being wired to one switch on the same circuit. They can also be wired separately to different switches.

Answer (score 1):

Code doesn't care if an exhaust fan is on the same circuit as lights.  In the vast majority of cases, an exhaust fan is a very small load on the order of 0.25A (I just installed bathroom lighting that was 0.5 amp), so it's no risk of overwhelming the circuit.

Code cares if bathroom **receptacles** are on the same circuit as exhaust fan, lights, and loads in other rooms.   The rules are a little complicated but the gist is that if this fan/light circuit powers bathroom receptacles then it can't power anything in any other room.

If you are merely upgrading to fan/light and not remodeling anything else, this should be grandfathered and you shouldn't need to deal with it.